# Show ko.validation error message in bootstrap popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover, knockout-validation

Already have experience using bootstrap popovers with separate div's... also have expience with ko.validation with native and custom validation rules but in input group text have unspected apereance:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-btn clearfix">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text: SupplierName" tabindex="-1"></button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" tabindex="-1">
         <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-bind="foreach: SupplierList, valueAllowUnset: true">
         <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.SupplierSelection"><span data-bind="text: text"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
          data-bind="value: Product, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'error' }">
</div>
```

Error menssage is showed under Product input text. It's posible get error span in a popover?

Answer (score 0):

After tons of searchs, test and reads I decide create [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Carlos_Mosquera/84KBL/), just be sure to press **RUN** button before your test, I'm still learning jsfiddle.

***KO.Validation problems***.

Suddenly I realize something wrong with KO.Validations: for more than one native validation rules configuration or for async rules with or without another rules `insertMessages: false` option **DON'T WORK**, may be I'm wrong... verify for your self.

**Valor** and **Valor3** controls have spected behavior... and **Valor2** and **Valor4** have original behavior.

Obviusly it will not be the last option and may be **Valor2** and **Valor4** have another error that I miss.

Here's the final code to solve problem:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.SetCSSandPopover = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var cssClass = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor);
        var obs = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor()).value;

        var decorateElement = obs.isModified() && !obs.isValid();
        if (decorateElement) {
            $(element).parent().addClass(cssClass);
            $(element).parent().parent().addClass(cssClass);
            console.log($(element).parent().parent());
            // insertMessages: false NEVER WORK with more than one validator o asyn rules
            $(element).next().attr("hidden", false);
            var msg = $(element).next()[0].outerHTML; // BEFORE hide message span
            $(element).next().attr("hidden", true);
            $(element).removeAttr("title");
            $(element).parent().parent().popover({
                trigger: "hover",
                html: true,
                title: "Corregir el error:",
                content: msg,
                container: "body",
                placement: "bottom"
            });
        } else {
            $(element).parent().removeClass(cssClass);
            $(element).parent().parent().removeClass(cssClass);
            $(element).parent().parent().popover("destroy");
        }
    }
};
```